# Thesis publication

Tags: discussion

I have been trying to publish my Master's thesis, I am sure It's an idea that what spreading. I would like to know if i can publish the thesis here on this site, and if so please how can I go about it?

Comment: No, you cannot publish your thesis here.  Please see the [help] for more information about this site.

Answer (score 17):

This is a question-and-answer site, not a publishing platform.

If you want to publish your master’s thesis, the best way is to convert it to a proper journal article (or conference paper, if that is a thing in your field). Your supervisor is probably the best person to advise you on this.

Comment: Or, especially in the humanities, publish it as a book.  If you just put it on the web, you will be in the company of all the kooks who do that, too.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the amazing answer by @Wrzlprmft, I have the following to make you **aware** of few things:

Many publishers, mostly 'unknown' and 'business oriented' ones do take advantage of the weak situations of the Graduate students by claiming that they would publish the whole thesis as a book.

One such example is Lambert Academic Publishing (LAP) whose status to be called as a legit publisher is highly questionable. Even I was about to get trapped by them. Have a look at the following questions:

- [Is Lambert Academic Publishing a reputable company?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2513/is-lambert-academic-publishing-a-reputable-company)
- [Be alert: LAP s[c|p]am](http://chemistry.ws.gc.cuny.edu/2014/06/03/be-alert-lambert-academic-publishing-spam/)
- [Your Thesis and the Predatory Publisher](https://library.bond.edu.au/news/46287/your-thesis-and-predatory-publisher) (you must read this)

Another example is OmniScriptum. [Read the blog here.](http://www.guide2research.com/tutorials/avoid-omniscriptum-to-re-publish-your-thesis-and-other-scientific-papers)

Be careful, it is your hard work produced as a thesis. You might lose copyright, ownership, and then left with nothing. Look how much they are earning from your hard work ([a sample e-shopping site](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_1_8?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=lambert%20academic%20publishing&sprefix=lambert%20%2Caps%2C358&crid=23PVVFINIYF47)).

If you want slightly faster publication (i.e. the time to get published), target high tier conferences in your field. (I am assuming here that you belong to Engineering fields)